# How can I cast an AD Attribute in a filter condition when calling Get-ADUser in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, type-conversion

**What I am trying to do:**
Return a list of AD users filtered by the date stored in an AD attribute using PowerShell.

**The problem**
The date I want to filter on is stored in an AD attribute with a string data type, specifically `extensionAttribute12`. This is non-negotiable with the people I am writing the script for.

I'm having trouble getting the syntax right in my filter to cast that string to a date before the comparison.

**Here's my non-working code:**

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$CurrentDate = $CurrentDate.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
$OU = "OU=PIV_Users,OU=FakeOU,DC=fake,DC=com"
$30Days = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope OneLevel -Filter {(extensionAttribute12 -notlike "*" -or extensionAttribute12 -le $30days) -and (enabled -eq $true) -and (whencreated -lt $30Days)} -Properties * |
    Select-Object Name, samAccountName, extensionAttribute12, whenCreated, enabled, employeeType
```

**This is the error:**

> Get-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.DateTime'.
>   Parameter name: extensionAttribute12
>   At line:9 char:1

I tried adding a cast as follows

```
... -or **[DateTime]extensionAttribute12** -le $30days) ...
```

Which gave me this error:

> Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: '(extensionAttribute12 -notlike "*" -or [DateTime]extensionAttribute12 -le $30days) -and (enabled -eq $true) -and (whencreated -lt $30Days)'
>   Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '40'.
>   At line:9 char:1

Comment: I don't think that's possible in an AD search string. You need to do it in a `Where-Object` condition after fetching the data.

Comment: Can you provide an example in an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: Can't test it,since i dont have active directory module on my local machine, can you try below `Get-ADUser -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope OneLevel  | where { $_.extensionAttribute12 -notlike "*" .....other properties} |
    Select-Object Name, samAccountName, extensionAttribute12, whenCreated, enabled, employeeT`

Comment: That worked. Please enter it as an answer so I can upvote and accept it. You deserve the unicorn tears!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge it's not possible to cast attributes to a different type in an AD search string. Despite the scriptblock-like notation the argument to the parameter `-Filter` is essentially a query string.

What you can do is do the filtering via `Where-Object` after fetching the objects. That's not optimal (because your AD query will return more objects than it needs to), but in this case I don't see another way. Make sure, however, that you only move those parts of the filter to the `Where-Object` that won't work otherwise, so that `Where-Object` doesn't need to process *all* user objects.

```
Get-ADUser-Filter {extensionAttribute12 -notlike '*' -and enabled -eq $true -and whencreated -lt $30Days} ... |
    Where-Object { [DateTime]extensionAttribute12 -le $30days } |
    ...
```

Comment: To address your concern about returning too many objects, I left most of my conditions in the Get-ADUser filter to minimize the objects in the initial pull and only applied the filter where I needed the type conversion in the WhereObject section's filter. Thanks!